# How to specify local instead of installed Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

So I'm trying to run the test-suite in a local copy of a Gem. I have updated the Gemfile to point to the path: `gem 'name', path: '.'` but this does not achieve the intended effect.

When I run one of the tests it requires the gem from my rvm Gem path anyways. I've tried adding the current path `(pwd)` before the rvm paths in the related environmental variables (GEM_PATH, GEM_HOME) -- but this is also ignored.

Comment: Please paste instruction that fails. Instructions like "require" should not fail, because they base on relative paths.

Comment: @konrad it doesn't fail, but the require loads form the `~/.rvm/gems` directory anyways when I run the tests.

Comment: Can you paste the require command?

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after Gemfile was changed?

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning what test suite you're using, but let's assume you use RSpec, did you try?

```
bundle exec rspec
```

Basically what I'm trying to say is: prefix whatever command you use to run your tests with: "bundle exec", that should use your gem defined in the local folder